# How to make a !boolean variable say 0 in Python

Tags: python, boolean

I'm calling winOrLose 1 or 0. I tried !myVariable in python and it said "invalid syntax error"

```
    if (battles[idx]['outcome'] == 'victory'):
        winOrLose = 1
    elif (battles[idx]['outcome'] == 'defeat'):
        winOrLose = 0
```

That works fine. If I do this:

```
    newFileWriter.writerow([rightPlayersID, rightPlayerCharacters, not winOrLose])
```

not winOrLose returns "False" instead of 0... even though winOrLose is 1. How do I do this elegantly? I think the data should say "0" instead of "false" because I'm using it for machine learning. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `(0 if winOrLose is 1 else 1)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Call your variable something like `won`. If you win, set this to `True` otherwise to `False`. Then your code will look like this.

```
if won:  
   print ("I won!")
else:
   print ("I lost")
```

To negate it, use the `not` operator. So,

```
if not won:
  print ("I lost!")
```

Much more readable than `wonorlost`. As for making it an integer, you can use `1 if won else 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple algebra:

```
1 - 0 == 1
1 - 1 == 0
```

So `lambda x: 1 - x` is your negation function.

Comment: Your solution is more elegant!

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to an integer using the int() function

```
newFileWriter.writerow([rightPlayersID, rightPlayerCharacters, int(not winOrLose)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for your conditional:

```
winOrLose = 1 if (battles[idx]['outcome'] == 'victory') else 0
```

Then for writing, use the code as it is:

```
newFileWriter.writerow([rightPlayersID, rightPlayerCharacters, not winOrLose])
```

However, the caveat of using such conditional statement is any other input than 'victory' will give 0 (as it is self-evident by the code).

As for the logical operator `!`. In Python, the logical operators are the following: `and`, `or`, and `not`. Hence, `not` is the equivalent of `!` in Python.

Answer (score -1):

Just convert your answer to an integer.
either by :

```
int(not winorlose)
```

Or by:

```
if not winorlose == True:
    winorlose = 1
else:
    winorlose = 0
```

I believe python does not support the ! operator.